# How values are evaluated in this expression in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

I have an expression in a program, initial value of `i = 10`

```
int j = i++ + i++;
```

it sets `j as 20` 
but

```
int j = i++ + ++i;
```

it sets `j as 22`
Why is there a difference of two between statements? I think, difference should be of 1.
I know this is undefined in C, but why `GCC` is doing such things?

Comment: Why do you think the difference should be 1?

Comment: What part of "undefined" do you want us to define for you?

Comment: @DavidBrown: maybe someone could think the difference should be 1 because he can't find a "consistent behavior" that evaluates the first expression to 20 and the second to 22, and/or why a compiler would choose that way, what are the benefits...

Comment: in first statement, value of first i++ should be 10 and second i++ should use 11, I think. So it should give 21. If it is incorrect, then how values are used in second statemnet

Comment: Closed as exact duplicate? Why? I can't see the same question, nor the answer to this question in the accepted answer of the possible duplicate.

Comment: @neel what if `++i` is evaluated first?

Comment: Why do people close questions and never come back again to read comments? I don't think this is a nice use of rep, it's like downvote without a comment to explain why...

Comment: @DavidBrown because postincrement has higher priority then preincrement

Comment: @neel It has to do with the order in which the operands of `+` are evaluated. If the right argument is evaluated first it will be 22. However in C the order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified.

Comment: @DavidBrown but according to precedence of operators postincrement will happen first then preincrement and then addition.

Comment: @neel: no, operator precedence doesn't apply here. It would in an expression like "++i++" (if that was well-defined). Nothing defines which operand (`a` or `b`) is evaluated first in `a + b`, regardless of what a and b are (plain constants or complex expressions).

Answer (score -1):

For i++ it is like: first do the equation then increment i.

For ++ i is like: first increment i then do the equation.

so i guess i++ + ++i is interpreted as i + (++(++i)) so thats the result is 22.

Wired things happen with wired syntax just dont do stuff like this ;).

If i'm right ++i + ++i would be 22 also.

Comment: It's interpreted as `(i++) + (++i)`. `++++i` is not valid syntax.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question asks why the compiler acts this way, knowing this is UB, like the answer says.

Comment: hm, ok :(, should stop trying to interpret bad syntax. its a waste of time